# Multilevel regression problem: some level 2 cases are part of more than one level 1 category

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am new to multilevel models and I am basically wondering whether I can use a multilevel model at all, given the structure of my data.

I have collected data on membership of lobby groups in committees used by the Directorates-General (DGs) of the European Commission (the DGs are a bit like ministries in a national context). I have data on the number of committee seats occupied by each group for all DGs. Level 2 of the analysis would be lobby groups, level 1 would be the DGs.

Now, my problem is that many lobby groups are present in more than one DG. It is my understanding that multilevel regression should normally only be used if the cases on the lower level are nested in those of the higher level (i.e. students are parts of a class, classes are part of a school, etc.). In effect, the "students" (lobby groups) in my data are members of several "classes" (DGs) each. Is it still possible to do a multilevel model in this case?

I am thinking of "forcing" the lobby groups to be nested in the DGs by adding data rows, so that one lobby group present in 5 DGs effectively becomes 5 identical lobby groups present in 1 DG each. Is this advisable?

Comment: See http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch2.pdf for an example of cross classified random effects.

Comment: What is it you are trying to model?